# How to profile a script which uses python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, profiling, qutip

I have a script file which uses the function parallel_map.
( [source code of qutip.parallel.parallel_map](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/master/qutip/parallel.py)) from a package [QuTiP](http://qutip.org/) . As one would see on clicking the [source code](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/master/qutip/parallel.py) for the function, it uses the multiprocess module of python. 
I looked at answers of [serial version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script/49173782#49173782). I decided upon [Snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) on reading [zaxiliu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37431235/7952027).
But naively trying it on my code fails. So what must I do to profile my code? My heart is not set on [Snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/).  I don't mind using any other graphical tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Doesn't satisfy the question requirements fully, but will work if nothing else is available*

Try using serial_map instead of parallel_map from the same [module](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/master/qutip/parallel.py). 
Replace (or better yet comment out) the line

> from qutip.parallel import parallel_map

with

> from qutip.parallel import serial_map

Now you have a serial implementation of code. This can be profiled using those described in [serial version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script/49173782#49173782) of your question. 
After this (assuming you go ahead with [Snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/))

- make the profile file

  > python -m cProfile -o program.prof my_program.py
- Run [Snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) on the profile file generated in the previous step

  > snakeviz program.prof